# Can you help identify my new LEGO set? Round glass door, black and red hoods, gray and black with a few red pieces

Tags: set-identification

I have a new LEGO set that I can't identify. I have looked all over Google. It came with a round glass door that looks like it could probably be a trap door and a plain black head and a grumpy face head. Also there is a black hood or helmet thing and a red one that cover the whole face but those are the only distinctive pieces. The whole set is mostly gray and black with a few red pieces.

Comment: Welcome Mesha! Could you please take a picture of the set and add it to your question? LEGO has made thousands of sets and your description is not enough to distinguish clearly which set you have.

Answer (score 7):

As Phil mentioned, it's hard to give a definitive answer without a picture to help, but based on your description, it sounds like you may have at least part of [Death Star Final Dual (75093)](http://brickset.com/sets/75093-1/Death-Star-Final-Duel):

[image: 75093]

This set is the only one I'm aware of that:

- Is mostly gray with a little red
- Includes a non-printed black minifig head
- Includes a black hood element
- Includes a red element that covers the entire face
- Includes large round transparent elements

Comment: *bows in reverence*